# Angular Google Maps API

Tags: angular, laravel, api, google-maps

Good day! i have an angular project that has a google map. i want to place a marker in my google map using data from my api.

this is my code from home.component.ts in angular:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: string = '';
  lng: string = '';
  location: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getLocation().subscribe( data => {
      this.location = data
      console.log(data)
      this.lat = data.latitude;
      this.lng = data.longitude; 
      }
    );
  }
```

it can place a marker from an api that has a single object like this:

```
{
    "country": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "in_eu": false,
    "postal": "94035",
    "latitude": 37.386,
    "longitude": -122.0838,
}
```

it can plot the latitude and longitude on the google map.
BUT when i use my api it can't get the latitude and longitude inside my api because it is inside an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "bridge_id": 2147483647,
        "bridge_name": "DASAD",
        "bridge_description": "Concrete",
        "bridge_region": "NCR",
        "latitude": "14.5905",
        "longitude": "120.9781",
        "created_at": "2019-02-13 07:17:31",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-13 07:17:31"
    }
]
```

I really need to get latitude and longitude from my api inside the array. any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: You can take help from this https://therichpost.com/angular-7-google-maps-working-example ...

Comment: i tried something but it didnt work

Comment: did you check above link?

Comment: I am basically Angular developer

Comment: i am new in angular. i just started days ago. i really dont understand anything from the given link. i have laravel project as my backend which provides the json data using Restful API. i cant seem to call the coordinates inside the array of the json data. but if theres only one object i can call the coordinates.

Comment: Okay I can help you. you are doing job, or you can assign me that project.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getLocation().subscribe( data => {
      this.location = data[0].
      console.log(data)
      this.lat = this.location.latitude;
      this.lng = this.location.longitude; 
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: src/app/home/home.component.ts(59,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: have you closed the file ? } is missing at the end.